# What can a token with a role of Guest or Reporter do when given scopes to read and write the repository?

Tags: gitlab

If I create a Project Access Token, or Personal Access Token (PAT) token with a role of Guest, and a scope such that it can read_repository and write_repository, what can that token actually do? I'm getting a 403 when I try to use it.

```
$ git clone https://foo:myToken@gitlab.awe.eco.cpanel.net/evancarroll/foo.git
Cloning into 'foo'...
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://acme.net/evancarroll/foo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Presumably nothing.**

But there is already an issue which addresses this.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/407725